# Timeline Progress bar for AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avplayer, uiprogressview

`AVPlayer` is fully customizable, unfortunately there are convenient methods in `AVPlayer` for showing the time line progress bar.

```
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:URL];
AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer] retain];[self.view.layer addSubLayer:playerLayer];
```

I have an progress bar that indicates the how video has been played, and how much remained just as like `MPMoviePlayer`.

So how to get the timeline of video from `AVPlayer` and how to update the progress bar

Suggest me.

Comment: Please consider using AVPlayerViewController. It is very simple to do playback (but may not suite your needs.). Just saying in case you're not aware of it. (edit) - Oops this is three years ago :P.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Please use the below code which is from apple example code "AVPlayerDemo".

```
    double interval = .1f;  

    CMTime playerDuration = [self playerItemDuration]; // return player duration.
    if (CMTIME_IS_INVALID(playerDuration)) 
    {
        return;
    } 
    double duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(playerDuration);
    if (isfinite(duration))
    {
        CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth([yourSlider bounds]);
        interval = 0.5f * duration / width;
    }

    /* Update the scrubber during normal playback. */
    timeObserver = [[player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(interval, NSEC_PER_SEC) 
                                                          queue:NULL 
                                                     usingBlock:
                                                      ^(CMTime time) 
                                                      {
                                                          [self syncScrubber];
                                                      }] retain];


- (CMTime)playerItemDuration
{
    AVPlayerItem *thePlayerItem = [player currentItem];
    if (thePlayerItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay)
    {        

        return([playerItem duration]);
    }

    return(kCMTimeInvalid);
}
```

And in syncScrubber method update the UISlider or UIProgressBar value.

```
- (void)syncScrubber
{
    CMTime playerDuration = [self playerItemDuration];
    if (CMTIME_IS_INVALID(playerDuration)) 
    {
        yourSlider.minimumValue = 0.0;
        return;
    } 

    double duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(playerDuration);
    if (isfinite(duration) && (duration > 0))
    {
        float minValue = [ yourSlider minimumValue];
        float maxValue = [ yourSlider maximumValue];
        double time = CMTimeGetSeconds([player currentTime]);
        [yourSlider setValue:(maxValue - minValue) * time / duration + minValue];
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the variable timeObserver for?

Comment: you need the timeObserver to actually cancel 'observing' and you also need to retain it, as long as you want to observe.. You can read the apple docu about addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:

Answer (score 24):

Thanks to iOSPawan for the code!
I simplified the code to the necessary lines. This might be more clear to understand the concept. Basically I have implemented it like this and it works fine.

Before starting the video:

```
__weak NSObject *weakSelf = self;    
[_player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0 / 60.0, NSEC_PER_SEC)
                                      queue:NULL
                                 usingBlock:^(CMTime time){
                                                [weakSelf updateProgressBar];
                                             }];

[_player play];
```

Then you need to have a method to update your progress bar:

```
- (void)updateProgressBar
{
    double duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(_playerItem.duration);
    double time = CMTimeGetSeconds(_player.currentTime);
    _progressView.progress = (CGFloat) (time / duration);
}
```

Comment: You're misusing __block here. __block is used if need to use assignment to the variable within the block. You probably meant to use __weak

Comment: Have updated your code. But additionally - you need to keep a reference to the object returned by addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval: in order for it to continue sending message and so that you can remove it later. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:

Comment: timeObserver should removed after stop playing `@result
       An object conforming to the NSObject protocol.  You must retain this returned value as long as you want the time observer to be invoked by the player.
       Pass this object to -removeTimeObserver: to cancel time observation.`

Comment: The weakSelf that was here was not working to me, but this did:   

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

Answer (score 12):

```
    let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: UIProgressViewStyle.Bar)
    self.view.addSubview(progressView)
    progressView.constrainHeight("\(1.0/UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)")
    progressView.alignLeading("", trailing: "", toView: self.view)
    progressView.alignBottomEdgeWithView(self.view, predicate: "")
    player.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1/30.0, Int32(NSEC_PER_SEC)), queue: nil) { time in
        let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(playerItem.duration)
        progressView.progress = Float((CMTimeGetSeconds(time) / duration))
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

I know it's an old question, but someone may find it useful. It's only Swift version:

```
 //set the timer, which will update your progress bar. You can use whatever time interval you want

 private func setupProgressTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.02, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] (completion) in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.updateProgress()
    })
}

//update progression of video, based on it's own data

private func updateProgress() {
    guard let duration = player?.currentItem?.duration.seconds,
        let currentMoment = player?.currentItem?.currentTime().seconds else { return }

    progressBar.progress = Float(currentMoment / duration)
}
```

Comment: thanks man, you saved me, spend lots of time on addObservers but not working. But thanks to you for this simple answer

Comment: There are lot of answers for this but none is accurate or complete or old, obsoleted. Yours is correct and updated as well. Thanks again

Comment: This is the best answer in 2021.

Answer (score 5):

Swifty answer to get progress:

```
private func addPeriodicTimeObserver() {
        // Invoke callback every half second
        let interval = CMTime(seconds: 0.5,
                              preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        // Queue on which to invoke the callback
        let mainQueue = DispatchQueue.main
        // Add time observer
        self.playerController?.player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: mainQueue) { [weak self] time in
            let currentSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(time)
            guard let duration = self?.playerController?.player?.currentItem?.duration else { return }
            let totalSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
            let progress: Float = Float(currentSeconds/totalSeconds)
            print(progress)
        }
    }
```

[Ref](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1385829-addperiodictimeobserver)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the following code works Swift 3:

```
var timeObserver: Any?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ........
    let interval = CMTime(seconds: 0.05, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    timeObserver = avPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { elapsedTime in
            self.updateSlider(elapsedTime: elapsedTime)     
        })
}

func updateSlider(elapsedTime: CMTime) {
    let playerDuration = playerItemDuration()
    if CMTIME_IS_INVALID(playerDuration) {
        seekSlider.minimumValue = 0.0
        return
    }
    let duration = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(playerDuration))
    if duration.isFinite && duration > 0 {
        seekSlider.minimumValue = 0.0
        seekSlider.maximumValue = duration
        let time = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(elapsedTime))
        seekSlider.setValue(time, animated: true)  
    }
}

private func playerItemDuration() -> CMTime {
    let thePlayerItem = avPlayer.currentItem
    if thePlayerItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
        return thePlayerItem!.duration
    }
    return kCMTimeInvalid
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    avPlayer.removeTimeObserver(timeObserver!)   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for timeline i do this

```
-(void)changeSliderValue {

double duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentItem.duration);

[lengthSlider setMaximumValue:(float)duration];

lengthSlider.value = CMTimeGetSeconds([self.player currentTime]);

int seconds = lengthSlider.value,minutes = seconds/60,hours = minutes/60;

int secondsRemain = lengthSlider.maximumValue - seconds,minutesRemain = secondsRemain/60,hoursRemain = minutesRemain/60;

seconds = seconds-minutes*60;

minutes = minutes-hours*60;

secondsRemain = secondsRemain - minutesRemain*60;

minutesRemain = minutesRemain - hoursRemain*60;

NSString *hourStr,*minuteStr,*secondStr,*hourStrRemain,*minuteStrRemain,*secondStrRemain;

hourStr = hours > 9 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",hours] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d",hours];

minuteStr = minutes > 9 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",minutes] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d",minutes];

secondStr = seconds > 9 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",seconds] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d",seconds];

hourStrRemain = hoursRemain > 9 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",hoursRemain] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d",hoursRemain];

minuteStrRemain = minutesRemain > 9 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",minutesRemain] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d",minutesRemain];

secondStrRemain = secondsRemain > 9 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",secondsRemain] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d",secondsRemain];

timePlayed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@:%@",hourStr,minuteStr,secondStr];

timeRemain.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@:%@:%@",hourStrRemain,minuteStrRemain,secondStrRemain];
```

And import CoreMedia framework

lengthSlider is UISlider

Comment: i am playing song from url . but at CMTime duration and CMTime currentTime i am getting 0 . what is the problem here for 0 value ? do you know the solution ?

Comment: here's documentation about this:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1389386-duration

Answer (score 0):

I took the answers from the iOSPawan and Raphael and then adapted to my needs.
So I have music and UIProgressView which is always in loop and when you go to the next screen and come back the the song and the bar continued where they were left.

Code:

```
@interface YourClassViewController (){

    NSObject * periodicPlayerTimeObserverHandle;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayer *player;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIProgressView *progressView;

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if(_player != nil && ![self isPlaying])
    {
        [self musicPlay];
    }
}


-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if (_player != nil) {

        [self stopPlaying];
    }
}

//   ----------
//     PLAYER
//   ----------

-(BOOL) isPlaying
{
    return ([_player rate] > 0);
}

-(void) musicPlay
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[_player currentItem]];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    periodicPlayerTimeObserverHandle = [_player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0 / 60.0, NSEC_PER_SEC)
                                                                             queue:NULL
                                                                        usingBlock:^(CMTime time){
                                                                            [weakSelf updateProgressBar];
                                                                        }];
    [_player play];
}


-(void) stopPlaying
{
    @try {

        if(periodicPlayerTimeObserverHandle != nil)
        {
            [_player removeTimeObserver:periodicPlayerTimeObserverHandle];
            periodicPlayerTimeObserverHandle = nil;
        }

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];
        [_player pause];
    }
    @catch (NSException * __unused exception) {}
}


-(void) playPreviewSong:(NSURL *) previewSongURL
{
    [self configureAVPlayerAndPlay:previewSongURL];
}


-(void) configureAVPlayerAndPlay: (NSURL*) url {

    if(_player)
        [self stopPlaying];

    AVAsset *audioFileAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:audioFileAsset];
    _player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    [_player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

    CRLPerformBlockOnMainThreadAfterDelay(^{
        NSError *loadErr;
        if([audioFileAsset statusOfValueForKey:@"playable" error:&loadErr] == AVKeyValueStatusLoading)
        {
            [audioFileAsset cancelLoading];
            [self stopPlaying];
            [self showNetworkError:NSLocalizedString(@"Could not play file",nil)];
        }
    }, NETWORK_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
}


- (void)updateProgressBar
{

    double currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(_player.currentTime);
    if(currentTime <= 0.05){
        [_progressView setProgress:(float)(0.0) animated:NO];
        return;
    }

    if (isfinite(currentTime) && (currentTime > 0))
    {
        float maxValue = CMTimeGetSeconds(_player.currentItem.asset.duration);
        [_progressView setProgress:(float)(currentTime/maxValue) animated:YES];
    }
}


-(void) showNetworkError:(NSString*)errorMessage
{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"No connection", nil) message:errorMessage preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil) style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        // do nothing
    }]];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if (object == _player && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (_player.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            [self showNetworkError:NSLocalizedString(@"Could not play file", nil)];
        } else if (_player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");
            [TLAppAudioAccess setAudioAccess:TLAppAudioAccessType_Playback];
            [self musicPlay];

        } else if (_player.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown");
        }
    }
}


- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {

    if ([notification.object isEqual:self.player.currentItem])
    {
        [self.player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
        [self.player play];
    }
}


-(void) dealloc{

    @try {
        [_player removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
    }
    @catch (NSException * __unused exception) {}
    [self stopPlaying];
    _player = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

technically you don't need a timer for this one.
Just add property

```
    private var isUserDragingSlider: Bool = false
```

Then you need to set up a slider target.

**STEP 1**

```
    self.timeSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSliderChangeValue(slider:event:)), for: .allEvents)
```

and in func handleSliderChangeValue you need to add this:

**STEP 2**

```
    @objc
func handleSliderChangeValue(slider: UISlider, event: UIEvent) {
    if let touchEvent = event.allTouches?.first {
        switch touchEvent.phase {
        case .began:
            self.isUserDragingSlider = true
        case .ended:
            self.isUserDragingSlider = false
            self.updateplayerWithSliderChangeValue()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

and in the end, you need to update your player with the selected time from a slider.

**STEP 3**

```
    func updateplayerWithSliderChangeValue() {
    if let duration = player?.currentItem?.duration {
        let totalSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
        if !(totalSeconds.isNaN || totalSeconds.isInfinite) {
            let newCurrentTime: TimeInterval = Double(self.timeSlider.value) * CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
            let seekToTime: CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(newCurrentTime, preferredTimescale: 600)
            self.player?.seek(to: seekToTime)
            self.isUserDragingSlider.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

And last thing, You need to update your code. Video is updating your slider.

**STEP 4**

```
func setupSliderValue(_ seconds: Float64) {
    guard !(seconds.isNaN || seconds.isInfinite) else {
        return
    }
    
    if !isUserDragingSlider {
        if let duration = self.player?.currentItem?.duration {
            let durationInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
            self.timeSlider.value = Float(seconds / durationInSeconds)
        }
    }
}
```

So main problem here is that when we move the slider we have a conflict between updating the slider ( from video ) and updating the video with our slider change.

That is why the slider is not working well. When you block updates from video time to slider with **isUserDragingSlider** all is working fine.