# Avplayer video playing Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I am working on App in which I want to display current playing time and total time of video. I got the total time. Now for showing current playing time Which method will get called. Can anyone help? I have used avplayer. This is the code:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.avplayer pause];
    self.avplayer = [AVQueuePlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
    self.avplayer = nil;
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:NO];

    AVPlayerItem *currentItem = self.avplayer.currentItem;
    CMTime duration = currentItem.duration; //total time
    CMTime currentTime = currentItem.currentTime; //playing time

    NSUInteger durationSeconds = (long)CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
    NSUInteger minutes = floor(durationSeconds % 3600 / 60);
    NSUInteger seconds = floor(durationSeconds % 3600 % 60);
    NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld", (unsigned long)minutes, (unsigned long)seconds];
    NSLog(@"Time|%@", time);
    lblTotaltime.text = time;


    NSUInteger durationSeconds1 = (long)CMTimeGetSeconds(currentTime);
    NSUInteger minutes1 = floor(durationSeconds1 % 3600 / 60);
    NSUInteger seconds1 = floor(durationSeconds1 % 3600 % 60);
    NSString *time1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld", (unsigned long)minutes1, (unsigned long)seconds1];
    NSLog(@"Time|%@", time1);
    lblRemaningTime.text = time1;
}

#pragma mark PlayerMethods
- (void)itemDidFinishPlaying:(NSNotification *)notification {
    AVPlayerItem *player = [notification object];
    [player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];

}
- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {

    AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];
    [p seekToTime:CMTimeMake(0, 3)];
}

- (void)playerStartPlaying
{
    [self.avplayer play];
}
```

Comment: show your tried code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the  current played time by using `currentItem` property using `AVPlayerItem`

```
AVPlayerItem *getcurrentItem = yourAVPlayerName.currentItem;
```

for get total Duration

```
CMTime fullDuration = getcurrentItem.duration;
```

for get current Time

```
CMTime playercurrentTime = getcurrentItem.currentTime;
```

alternate

```
NSTimeInterval playercurrentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(getcurrentItem.currentTime);
NSLog(@" get current Time of video :%f ",playercurrentTime);
```

Comment: I got the duration. but exactly i am not getting where to write the code for displaying current play time of video

Comment: @Niharika - if your yourAVPlayerName is global after the video started you will get this, you can use anywhere in your class

Comment: reason for downvote, if downvote is reasonable i will update my answer

Comment: ok. I have added my code. the only problem i am facing is played time is not  updating runtime.:(

Comment: @Niharika - i understand , see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725505/timeline-progress-bar-for-avplayer

Comment: inside the following method `playerStartPlaying` add the `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval` and update your player time

Comment: Ok. I will check . Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @Niharika - if you not get the answer, ping me we will move on step

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150908/discussion-between-niharika-and-anbu-karthik).